# IOS universal app image resolutions

Tags: ios, universal

Must a universal IOS app supply all images at the recommended scales @2x, @3x as well as non retina (@1x)? Is this a requirement to pass the app review?

What if I supply only one set of images at high enough resolution to look sharp on a big screen and would then scale down to smaller screen sizes? There are of coarse performance penalties for the compositing engine when scaling down but if performance is not noticeably degraded and all looks good does it matter?

Scrollviews are at the very core of my app. I have therefore created images that are at an arbitrarily higher resolution then they need to be for most of the time. That is until the user zooms to a level where each image might occupy the whole screen and the benefit of high resolutions are then realised.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a requirement to pass the app review?

No. But read on...

> What if I supply only one set of images at high enough resolution to look sharp on a big screen and would then scale down to smaller screen sizes?

Then you'd be wasting memory and making the rendering engine work unnecessarily hard. (Keep in mind that images have two dimensions, so memory usage goes up *exponentially* as they get larger.)

> if performance is not noticeably degraded and all looks good does it matter?

Apple is very clear: they'd rather you didn't do that.

> I have therefore created images that are at an arbitrarily higher resolution then they need to be for most of the time. That is until the user zooms to a level where each image might occupy the whole screen and the benefit of high resolutions are then realised

But "arbitrarily higher" is just plain wrong; you need to scale the image down in real time to the highest size it would ever need to be *on this device*. You know how to scale an image down in code, don't you?

Also... You may not be aware that CATiledLayer will meet exactly this situation: it will take multiple images at different resolutions and substitute them for one another as the user zooms. That way, you're using *at any given moment* only the resolution you actually need.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by scale down in code. Basically I have essentially created sprite images. There may be several on screen all at once. The user may decide to pinch zoom around any one of these to a greater or lesser degree. I've arranged it so that at maximum zoom, a sprite would be displaying at a one to one pixel display ratio on the largest screen available. Each sprite is in fact a complex view hierarchy of moving parts and are in fact UIView subclasses. They are scaled to be a certain percentage of the screen size to accommodate different size devices.

Comment: "Scale down in code" means, we load, say, a 300x300 image and turn it into a 100x100 image for purposes of display. That sort of change is extremely significant: the second image uses about one-tenth the memory of the first! — Not sure I understand what you mean by sprite images. But none of what you just said changes anything about what I said. :) You should, in my opinion, learn about how to scale down an image in code, and about how to use CATiledLayer.

Comment: I did look at CATiledLayer in the past and I thought it might not be a good fit for me. It seemed to apply more to zooming a large background image to reveal greater detail with smooth scrolling. But I have a very complex view hierarchy where the background image itself is not important. I will look at it again though. --- The scaling down you refer to is essentially rendering on the fly then as opposed to stretching/ shrinking UIImageViews. So using core graphics style contexts e.g CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);

Comment: Should have been drawInRect: